# Iterating List of SQL.Row with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark.SQL.Row that looks something like this:

```
my_row = Row(id = 1,
    value = [Row(id = 1, value = "value1"), Row(id = 2, value = "value2")])
```

I'd like to get the value from each of the nested rows using something like:

```
[x.value for x in my_row.value]
```

The problem is that when I iterate, the entire row is converted into tuples,

```
my_row = (1, [(1, "value1"), (2, "value2")])
```

and I lose the schema. Is there a way to iterate and retain the schema for the list of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise `pyspark.sql.row` is actually a `tuple`:

```
isinstance(my_row, tuple)
# True
```

Since Python tuples are immutable the only option I see is rebuild `Row` from scratch:

```
d = my_row.asDict()
d["value"] = [Row(value=x.value) for x in  my_row.value]
Row(**d)

## Row(id=1, value=[Row(value='value1'), Row(value='value2')])
```